# RadComboBox:white space appearing at the bottom of the dropdownlist

Tags: whitespace, dropbox, space, telerik-combobox

I got a RadComboBox from Telerik, and i populate it with some data from my database.

Let's say i have 10 items of 20pixels high each, that would make the drop down list of 200pixels high. Right now, i force the control to have a max height of 100px, so i should see a scrollbar. When i scroll my box, i got about 100px of white space at the end of my list, making the dropdownlist way to long, about 300 pixels.

These are the relevant properties of my RadComboBox:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ... DropDownWidth="280px" MaxHeight="120px" NoWrap="True" />
```

**At the end of the list, i got white space**, white lines, **equivalent size of the height of the control** (120px of white space). I found nothing so far about that. Anyone got a clue?

[image: image of my combo box white space]

Comment: telerik version 2012.1.215.35 for ASP.NET ajax

Comment: And this behavior is exclusive for IE 8.0.6001.18702. In Firefox 18.0, the scrollbar seems longer but the browser block the scroll, so we don't see the white space. Same thing in Chrome 24.0.1312.56 m. Unfortunatly my project is exclusivly for IE...

Comment: Any other leads? I'm experiencing this with Telerik's newest, 2013.2.910.40. Found [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/radcombobox-autoresize-and-dropdown-position.aspx) thread on their support forum but none of the suggested workarounds works for me.

Comment: I see this same behavior in the RadComboBox WPF control too.  Now idea on how to fix it yet.